# Looping through emitted data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I pass some data with emit, it's logging as:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
```

But I want to loop through my data structure of:

```
users:
            {
                'names': [],
                'addresses': [],
            }
```

Looping through names then addresses.

But when I try to do this I get:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: this.users.forEach is not a function"
```

Comment: What's the emit statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your `users` data as shown is an object, not an array, so it does not have a `forEach` method.

The object does contain two arrays inside it, `names` and `addresses`. Perhaps you meant to iterate through those arrays? Assuming that `this.users` is a valid reference to your `users` object, you could do:

```
this.users.names.forEach( function( name ) {
    // Do stuff with name
});

this.users.addresses.forEach( function( address ) {
    // Do stuff with address
});
```

Are `users.names` and `users.addresses` in a 1:1 correspondence, where `users.names[0]` and `users.addresses[0]` are both for the same user, and so on for `[1]`, `[2]`, etc.? In that case you could use:

```
this.users.names.forEach( ( name, i ) => {
    let address = this.users.addresses[i];
    // Do stuff with name and address
});
```

I used an arrow function here instead of a regular `function` to preserve `this`.

However, if the `names` and `addresses` arrays *are* in a 1:1 correspondence like this, I would recommend restructuring the `users` data if you are able to do that.

Instead of `users` being an object containing two parallel arrays, make `users` be the array, where each element of this array contains a `name` and `address` property. This way all the data for a user is grouped together for easy access. This will be especially helpful if you add other user fields such as `phone` or `email`:

```js
let users = [
    {
        "name": "Mike",
        "address": "California",
        "phone": "510-555-0001",
        "email": "mike@example.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Panthro",
        "address": "Oregon",
        "phone": "510-555-0002",
        "email": "panthro@example.com"
    }
];

users.forEach( function( user ) {
    console.log( user.name, user.address, user.phone, user.email );
});
```

As you can see, this way of structuring your user data makes it easy to access the individual data fields for each user.